# Given two lines in 3D space, determine all unknowns so that the lines only intersect once

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have two lines $L_1, L_2\in R^3$, and two unknowns $a,b \in R$. Say
$$L_1=\{ \lambda(a,0,2)+(1,1,4) \}, \space L_2=\{ \mu(b,3,1)+(2,-1,1) \}$$

How would you go about finding all pairs of $a,b$ so that both lines intersect only in one point?

If I equate the $x,y,z$ values of both lines, I end up with a system of three equations and four unknowns.
Solving that system, I get specific values for $\lambda, \mu$ and a linear relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Would the solution be all $a,b$ that satisfy that equation for the specific $\lambda, \mu$ values I determined? I feel like restraining the scalars $\lambda,\mu$ stops me from finding all possible $a,b$ combinations if that makes any sense.

I couldn't find any questions related to this specific problem; I only managed to find about line intersections *without* unknowns. I'd highly appreciate any hints on how to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two lines intersect at a point, then there exists $\lambda $ and $\mu$ such that

$ \begin{bmatrix} a && - b \\ 0 && - 3 \\ 2 && - 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  \lambda \\ \mu \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ - 3 \end{bmatrix} $

And this means that the column vector on the right hand side is a linear combination of the two column vectors on the left hand side.  Therefore, we must have

$ \begin{vmatrix} a && - b && 1 \\ 0 && - 3 && -2 \\ 2 && -1 && - 3 \end{vmatrix} = 0 $

This determinant evaluates to

$ a ( 9 - 2 ) + 2 ( 2 b + 3 ) = 0 $

i.e.

$ 7 a + 4 b + 6 = 0 $

This line in $(a,b)$ specifies exactly how to choose $a$ and $ b$ .

For example, if $ a = 2 $ then $ b = -5 $.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Two lines either intersect in zero points, one point, or are identical.  In your case, it is impossible for $L_1,L_2$ to be identical, since $(1,1,4) \ne (2,-1,1)$.  Therefore, your problem is equivalent to finding all $a,b$ such that $L_1,L_2$ have some intersection.  $L_1,L_2$ intersect if there is some $\lambda,\mu$ such that

$$\lambda(a,0,2) + (1,1,4) = \mu(b,3,1)+(2,-1,1).$$

Looking at the second and third coordinates, we find that

$$\lambda(0,2) + (1,4) = \mu(3,1) + (-1,1),$$

which happens iff $\mu=2/3, \lambda=-7/6$.  Plugging into the original equation and looking at the first coordinate, we find that

$$-7a/6 + 1 = 2b/3 + 2,$$

which holds iff $b=(-7a-6)/4$.

This then gives you the set of all $a,b$ combinations where the lines intersect once: $a,b$ are any two values such that $b=(-7a-6)/4$.

Comment: Thank you! Super clear.